# White space instead of repeating background image

Tags: html, css, background

I have currently re designed my portfolio site located at http://www.jn-design.co.uk

When the window is resized (to mimic smaller resolutions) I have a large white gap to the right of my website. I have tried various solutions , but none solve the problem without making other problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this, this should work.

```
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```